# Shell script to automatically unzip latest DB file

Tags: shell, sh

I have a folder where new versions of compressed DB files are stored. Each new version of the DB has a filename convention that indicates when it was created. When ever a DB needs to be restored it is always the latest version in the folder. Here are the contents of the sh file:

```
# Path to the Zip file
  filename="/Users/Documents/development/code/docker/data/2021_10_30__17_37_36.filename_db_backup_sql.qz"
    
    # Restore
    gunzip < $filename | docker exec -i database /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE
```

What I'd like to have is the shell script automatically load the latest DB without having to update the shell script itself with a new filename every time.

I'd like the script to look through all of the files in the folder, parse out the filenames and identify the latest one and load it automatically.

The filename format is:
YYYY_MM_DD__HH_MM_SS.filename_db_backup_sql.qz

Writing shell scrips is not my forte so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do this using `find` to find the most recently created by date, 
and file file type with `-name`:

```
filename=$(find /Users/Documents/development/code/docker/data -type f -name '*.qz' -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | tail -n 1)

echo $filename

gunzip < $filename | docker exec -i database /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE
```

`find`:  obviosly looking for the file in /Users/Documents/development/code/docker/data

`-type f`: looking for a file, not a directory

`-name '*.qz'`  look for any file with the `.qz` extension

`-printf`: format ->

`%T@ %p\n:`: File's last access time in the format

`sort -n`: numeric sort

`cut`: remove formatted date at the space `' '` delimiter `1637259734.8637336000 2021_10_30__17_37_36.filename_db_backup_sql.qz`

`tail -n 1`: output a single result

Comment: I get a couple of error messages with this code. If I use it as is from above I get this error message: `test.sh: line 26: $filename: ambiguous redirect` where line 26 is the gunzip statement. If I comment that line out for it to only echo the $filename I get this error message: `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`. Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: What OS are you on?  I have tried this on both Ubuntu and CentOs --  They both operate as expected.

Comment: If you are using Mac OS . the parameters might not match the ones I gave you.  If it is MacOS -- Try issuing the command `bash script.sh` as bash is Macs primary CLI tool.